# django: How to save value against nested models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have models with nested many-to-many relationships

**IndependentTest** have many-to-many relationship with **Protocols**

and **Protocols** have many-to-many relationship with **Format**.

So I need to save **test results** for a particular **User** against **IndependentTests**.

**EDIT:** Here are the models

```
class IndependentTest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    choice = models.ManyToManyField(to=TestChoice, null=True, blank=True)
    required = models.BooleanField()
    testType = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                                choices=Values.CUSTOM_ATTRIB_TYPES)

class TestProtocol(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    independent_test = models.ManyToManyField(IndependentTest,
                                              through='PIOrder')

class PIOrder(models.Model):
    protocol = models.ForeignKey(TestProtocol)
    independent = models.ForeignKey(IndependentTest)
    order = models.IntegerField()

class TestFormat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    test_protocol = models.ManyToManyField(TestProtocol, through='FPOrder')

class FPOrder(models.Model):
    format = models.ForeignKey(TestFormat)
    protocol = models.ForeignKey(TestProtocol)
    order = models.IntegerField()
```

**EDIT:** I don't know if this is a good approach, but I can make a new class

```
class CandidateTest (models.Model):
    test_value  = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    candidate   = models.ForeignKey(Candidate)
    test        = models.ForeignKey(IndependentTest)
    testProtocol = models.ForeignKey(TestProtocol)
    testFormat  = models.ForeignKey(TestFormat)
```

Although the results will be saved in test_value but what about any other data like the date or place the test was taken?

Comment: could you please post your models - it's easier to answer on your example

Comment: Sorry for that, I have posted the models. @init3